# How can I make this regex replace function efficient?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using this function to perform regex replace on `std::string`:

```
String regexReplace(String s,String search,String replace,String modifier,int user){
    bool case_sensitive=true,global=false;
    String replaced_string=s;
    if(modifier=="gi" || modifier=="ig"){global=true;case_sensitive=false;}
    else if(modifier=="i"){case_sensitive=false;}
    else if(modifier=="g"){global=true;}

    try {
        std::regex re (search);
        if(user==1){re=createRegex(search,case_sensitive);}
        else if(!case_sensitive){re= Regex (search, REGEX_DEFAULT | ICASE);}

        if(global){
        replaced_string=std::regex_replace (s,re,replace,std::regex_constants::format_default);
        }
        else{
        replaced_string=std::regex_replace (s,re,replace,NON_RECURSIVE_REGEX_REPLACE);
        }
    } 
    catch (std::regex_error& e) {
      printErrorLog("Invalid replace string regex: "+search);
      Exit(1);
    }
    return replaced_string;
}
```

`typedef`s and `#define`s used:

```
typedef std::regex Regex;
typedef std::string String;

#define REGEX_DEFAULT std::regex::ECMAScript
#define ICASE std::regex::icase
#define NON_RECURSIVE_REGEX_REPLACE std::regex_constants::format_first_only
```

But this function consumes approximately 0.3 seconds on 14x4 consecutive executions:

```
res=regexReplace(res,"([^\\.]*\\.\\d+?)0+$","$1","i",0);
res=regexReplace(res,"([^\\.]*\\.\\d+?)0+(e.*)$","$1$2","i",0);
res=regexReplace(res,"([^\\.]*)\\.0*$","$1","i",0);
res=regexReplace(res,"([^\\.]*)\\.0*(e.*)$","$1$2","i",0);
```

Can I make it more efficient to lessen the execution time?

Note:

The `createRegex()` function is not being called (`user=0` by default).

Comment: I suppose that answer depend on platform (compiler,os,c++runtime)

Comment: It depends on a lot of parameters including mainly your dev skills, but one approach might be to use a hand crafted parser instead of a regex as regex are powered by general purpose engines while you do know the specific needs of your case and as such can optimize better for it.